# C# uint64 -- Store data?

Tags: c#, types, primitive-types, uint64, ulong

Is there a better way to store numerical data in an uint64 other than using x digits for one piece, y digits for other stuff? (20 digits total to work with)

I am trying to store information about an object without having the overhead of making a struct or class. I need to get/set as fast as possible with minimal overhead.

Comment: Could you give example of these numbers?

Comment: Difficult to understand what do you mean for _overhead_. Managing this hybrid is not an overhead?

Comment: You can use specific bits (using [bitwise operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)) of the integer to store information, but in most cases I've seen, they're mostly microoptimizations and not worth doing. Can you give an example of what you would be storing?

Comment: Sure. Well, I am making a tile-based game (Minecraft, Terraria, etc) and I need a way to store the block data efficiently that allows for fast extraction of the properties such as: ID, shapeID, BiomeID, ownerID, etc. Classes and structs are too slow and too large for fast storage and operations.

So, an example could be: 00031000230745238653 ....
00031 = blockID
00023 = shapeID
074 = BiomeID
rest = ownerID

Comment: Overhead being time it takes to complete the operation.

Comment: I think struct handling will be faster than single value handling (to get blokID, ShapeID, etc from a single value). Note that Int32, Int64, UInt64, are all structs in .NET

Comment: An array? This sounds like a maintenance nightmare though.

Comment: Minecraft is not tile-based but voxel based game, as same teraria is 2d voxel not tile, tile game looks like http://www.cr31.co.uk/stagecast/art/pixel/game.gif

Comment: @Taumantis, Ah, right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @DarrenGourley, sorta, but I am using a multi-dimensional array of uint64[ , , ] to store the block data at X , Y , Z values so i can just get/set by: Data[10,5,7] = someUint64value;

Comment: Another possible issue. Given that the max value of uint64 is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615; what happens if the first digit needs to be something different than 1? I guess it can't be. I also need to ask how you're generating this number and retrieving data from it. I imagine this creates a big overhead?

Comment: I think you are focusing too much on his question ignoring the case and his comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as far as I know voxels coding. If you want to store "blocks" data that is defined one by one then you can use **interval tree** , where the key of each node is the start of a run and the value is the coordinate of the run. [Implemntation example](http://intervaltree.codeplex.com/).

Also, you NEVER store single block as class but SET of blocks for example block 3x3 can be done as:

[image]

as you see I just coded data position of 9 blocks in two bits
This is simplified method for which data size is not the problem but fast implementation of iteration that needs form you some algorithm.

Before you even start play with Voxels read these

[Let's Make a Voxel Engine](https://sites.google.com/site/letsmakeavoxelengine/)

[Damn, Voxel Data is BIG](http://johnwhigham.blogspot.com/2013/07/damn-voxel-data-is-big.html)

[Voxel engines are everywhere…](http://0fps.net/2012/01/14/an-analysis-of-minecraft-like-engines/)

[Voxel Engine – Data Storage](http://www.subterraneansoftware.com/run-based-voxel-engine/)

Internet is full of answeres, but these will give your information that you need. Also keyword that I think you were mising is **VOXEL**

Comment: Thanks for the links! I don't totally understand the tree thing but the links helped.

Answer (score 1):

If using `uint64` or `ulong` is not a fixed requirement, I suggest you use the [BigInteger class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It was designed to efficiently store arbitrarily-large numbers.

Is it efficient?  If you decompile the code, you'll see that they store an array of bits internally to manage the number. That is, with `N` bits, it stores a number up to `2^N - 1`.